# Find the diameter of iron ball.

Tags: geometry

> Iron weights $8$ times the weight of oak, Find the diameter of an iron ball whose weight is equal to that of a ball of oak $18$ cm in diameter.

$a)\quad   4.5\quad  cm \\\color{green}{b)\quad   9 \quad  cm}\\c)\quad   12\quad   cm\\d) \quad  15 \quad  cm$

I tried

$\dfrac43\times \pi\times (\dfrac{d}{2})^3 =8\times \dfrac43\times \pi\times (9)^3\\~\\
d=36\quad cm$

what is the mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since iron weighs $8$ times what oak weighs, you need the iron ball to have $\frac{1}{8}$ the volume of the oak ball.

$$\begin{align}
  \frac{4}{3} \times \pi \times \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^3 &=
  \color{red}{\frac{1}{8}} \times \frac{4}{3} \times \pi \times (9)^3  \\
  \frac{d^3}{8} &= \frac{1}{8} \times (9)^3  \\
  d^3 &= 9^3 \\
  d &= 9
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

More quickly,
since the weight is proportional
to the cube of the diameter,
inverting this relationship,
we have that
the diameter is proportional
to the cube root of the
weight.

Since the density is
8 times as much,
the diameter is
$\sqrt[3]{8}
= 2
$ times smaller
(for the heavier material).

Therefore,
the diameter is
$\dfrac{18}{2} = 9$.